# copying ssh id from debian to centos times out, how to debug?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, centos, headless

I'm setting up another pc on my network. it will eventually be headless.

It currently boots into the centos CLI ~ which is fine. now i want to copy over my ssh rsa key from my main debian pc to the new centos one.

I can ssh from debian to centos with 'normal password'

ssh-copy-id [userName]@192.168.100.169

the terminal will then ask for the password, and everything is fine, however when I attempt to copy my public key to the server using

ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub [userName]@192.168.100.169

the call will eventually time out... here is the output

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host 92.168.100.169 port 22: Connection timed out

I now that using a standard ssh login I can get the debug info, but how do I debug the ssy-copy-id command, i've tried

ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub -o -v [userName]@192.168.100.169
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub -v [userName]@192.168.100.169

but I just get errors for invalid options, so I have no way to debug what isn't working.

I've done a similar thing with other virtual machines (also running debian) and they have copied over the rsa key almost instantly, what config option have I got that is different between debian and Centos that is causing me grief ?

All help would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance

David

p.s. I've copied this question to here from my [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635263/copying-ssh-id-from-debian-to-centos-times-out-how-to-debug) question because I put it on the wrong site !

Comment: you do not use $192 ? this would evaluate to 192 th argument of calling shell. beside, there is a `[userName]`(leading [ ) and `userName]` (no leading [ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP of your target machine is
`192.168.100.169`, while the error says
`92.168.100.169` not reachable.

that's probably because there's a `$` sign after `@`, in front of the IP address in your command?

Comment: That is just so dopey ! Insane how some things can't be seen for looking.